# Searching through a String

Tags: haskell

I found a good example in a book that I'm trying to tackle. I'm trying to write a function called, "pointer" with the signature as, `pointer :: String -> Int`. It is going to take text with "pointers" that look like, [Int], and then return the total number of pointers found.

The text that the pointer function will examine will look like:

```
txt :: String
txt = "[1] and [2] are friends who grew up together who " ++
      "went to the same school and got the same degrees." ++
      "They eventually opened up a store named [2] which was pretty successful."
```

In the command line, we will run the code as follows:

```
> pointer txt 
3
```

The 3 signifies the number of pointers that were found.

WHAT I UNDERSTAND:

- I get that "words" will break down a string into a list with words.
  Example:

  > words "where are all of these apples?"

  ["where","are","all","of","these","apples?"]
- I get that "filter" will choose a specific element(s) in a list.
  Example:

  > filter (>3) [1,5,6,4,3]

  ```
       [5,6,4]
  ```
- I get that "length" will return the length of a list

WHAT I THINK I NEED TO DO:

```
Step 1) look at txt and then break it down into single words until you have a long list of words.
Step 2) use filter to examine the list for [1] or [2]. Once found, filter will place these pointers into an list.
Step 3) call the length function on the resulting list.
```

PROBLEM BEING FACED:

I'm having a tough time trying to take everything I know and implementing it.

Comment: So you just want to count the number of times the words `[1]` and `[2]` occur in a string?

Comment: Write a function `f :: String -> Bool` which is true iff the input string is a "pointer". Then your function is exactly as you've described it: `length . filter f . words`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hypothetical ghci session:

```
ghci> words txt
[ "[1]", "and", "[2]", "are", "friends", "who", ...]

ghci> filter (\w -> w == "[1]" || w == "[2]") (words txt)
[ "[1]", "[2]", "[2]" ]

ghci> length ( filter (\w -> w == "[1]" || w == "[2]") (words txt) )
3
```

You can make the last expression more readable using the `$` operator:

```
length $ filter (\w -> w == "[1]" || w == "[2]") $ words txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to find all patterns of type [Int] in a string – such as [3], [465], etc. and not only [1] and [2] the easiest would be to use regular expression:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoOverloadedStrings #-}

import Text.Regex.Posix

txt :: String
txt = "[1] and [2] are friends who grew up together who " ++
      "went to the same school and got the same degrees." ++
      "They eventually opened up a store named [2] which was pretty successful."

pointer :: String -> Int
pointer source = source =~ "\\[[0-9]{1,}\\]"
```

We can now run:

```
pointer txt
> 3
```

Comment: Since `OverloadedStrings` is normally off by default, you shouldn't need `{-# LANGUAGE NoOverloadedStrings #-}` unless the `.cabal` file for your project turns it on by default.

Answer (score 1):

This works for single digit "pointers":

```
pointer :: String -> Int
pointer ('[':_:']':xs) = 1 + pointer xs
pointer (_:        xs) = pointer xs
pointer _              = 0
```

This is better handled with parser combinators like those provided by ie. [Parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec), but this might be overkill.